# i am trying to get value of particular hidden input text box using jquery it's not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i tried before insert this

```
 var req=$('#'+investor_id+'#requestId');
 var requestId=document.getElementById(req).value;
 alert(requestId);)
```

code it's it's working fine but after it's not working, [here is code](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/9fTPh/5/)

Comment: You're going to need to be a bit more clear about what you're trying to do and what is not working.  I don't see any references to hidden fields or requestId in your fiddle source.

Comment: tip: `id` never start with numbers. change `form id="1848719408"`

Comment: here is link http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/9fTPh/5/

Comment: please create fiddle with minimum css/html and necessary JS

Comment: i change the code here is link http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/9fTPh/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your code a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/9fTPh/17/

That fiddle cleaned up your code slightly, but you should normally take this steps:

1) hit the 'tidyup' button, then look for missing });

2) don't use id's if they're not unique, just use class

3) you do not have to set an id on everything just to find it, all objects are relative to each other

Comment: you edited my code it looks very professional i like it, very nice i will follow this type of coding from now, thank you soo much

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you access element with its id instead of writing pipings. ID values are unique in document.
Try this code

```
 alert($('#requestId').val()); 
 //Check here for working demo http://jsfiddle.net/9fTPh/6/
```

Instead of

```
 var req=$('#'+investor_id+'#requestId');
 var requestId=document.getElementById(req).value;
 alert(requestId);
```

And in the fiddle you have provided code us  },)  are not correctly given.(Check with JsLint)

Comment: Check here http://jsfiddle.net/9fTPh/12/. Before providing a fiddle please check minimum things like },) missings... In your every fiddle JsLint is scolding us about } and )...